# Show another ViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

help me please. How can I show another view controller after dismissing the existing one? here is my code:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:
(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController{

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   ViewController *Vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
    [self presentModalViewController:Vc animated:YES];



}
```

My code doesn't work. Help me please. If i wrote NSLog after dismissingModalViewController, it shows me that NSLog, but ViewController won't show. thanks

Comment: Does ViewController have a view with anything in it (do you have xib file for ViewController)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` has been deprecated. Try doing:

```
- (void)matchmakerViewControllerWasCancelled:
(GKMatchmakerViewController *)viewController{

    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
         ViewController *Vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
         [self presentViewController:Vc animated:YES completion:^{}];
    }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply check this

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
Nextview *sec = [[Nextview alloc] initWithNibName:@"Nextview" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:sec animated:YES];
[sec release];
```

Hope this works.